# How to replce dataframe in postgresql table?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a PostgreSQL table named - net_position.
I want to replace a pandas data frame into PostgreSQL table using python.
data frame looks like this.[result_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS9Lo.png)

My approach is-

def replace_net_pos(np_trades):

```
try:
    conn_string = 'postgresql://postgres:Password@localhost:5432/trade_data'

    db = create_engine(conn_string)
    connection = db.connect()
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    # creating cursor to perform database operations
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Executing SQl query to delete data

    update_data = np_trades.to_sql(
        'net_position', con=connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    cursor.execute(update_data)
    connection.commit()

    # fetch result
    sql2 = "SELECT * from net_position"
    cursor.execute(sql2)
    resultant = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Result", resultant)

except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to postsql", error)

finally:
    if (connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("Post Sql connection is closed")
```

replace_net_pos(result_df)

.................
error getting--
Error while connecting to postsql Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: ...ELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;
^

Post Sql connection is closed
................................
but not getting data frame replaced.
can anyone please help.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your error, **sqlite_master** is mentioned. I think you should update settings configuration to postgresql.